# Wordpress White page with PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

I hosted a Wordpress website at home but now decided to hoste it elsewhere. Unfortunately after literally copying it to a new host I don't get it working. I only see PHP code printer without any errors.

Please take a look at this page so you can see for yourself:

```
errors[$code][] = $message; 
if ( ! empty($data) ) 
    $this->error_data[$code] = $data; 
} 
/**
* Retrieve all error codes. 
* * @since 2.1.0 
* @access public 
* * @return array List of error codes, if available. */ 
public function get_error_codes() { 
    if ( empty($this->errors) ) return array(); 
    return array_keys($this->errors); 
} 
/** 
* Retrieve first error code available. * 
* @since 2.1.0 
* @access public * 
* @return string|int Empty string, if no error codes. */ 
public function get_error_code() { 
    $codes = $this->get_error_codes(); 
    if ( empty($codes) ) return ''; 
    return $codes[0]; 
} 
/** 
* Retrieve all error messages or error messages matching code. * 
* @since 2.1.0 * 
* @param string|int $code Optional. Retrieve messages matching code, if exists. 
* @return array Error strings on success, or empty array on failure (if using code parameter). */ 
public function get_error_messages($code = '') { 
    // Return all messages if no code specified. 
    if ( empty($code) ) { 
        $all_messages = array(); 
        foreach ( (array) $this->errors as $code => $messages ) 
            $all_messages = array_merge($all_messages, $messages); 
        return $all_messages; 
    } 
    if ( isset($this->errors[$code]) ) 
        return $this->errors[$code]; 
    else 
        return array(); 
} 
/** 
* Get single error message. * 
* This will get the first message available for the code. If no code is 
* given then the first code available will be used. * 
* @since 2.1.0 * 
* @param string|int $code Optional. Error code to retrieve message. 
* @return string */ 
public function get_error_message($code = '') { 
    if ( empty($code) ) $code = $this->get_error_code(); 
    $messages = $this->get_error_messages($code); 
    if ( empty($messages) ) return ''; 
    return $messages[0]; 
} 
/** 
* Retrieve error data for error code. * 
* @since 2.1.0 * 
* @param string|int $code Optional. Error code. 
* @return mixed Null, if no errors. */ 
public function get_error_data($code = '') { 
    if ( empty($code) ) 
        $code = $this->get_error_code(); 
    if ( isset($this->error_data[$code]) ) 
        return $this->error_data[$code]; 
    return null; 
} 
/** 
* Add an error or append additional message to an existing error. * 
* @since 2.1.0 
* @access public * 
* @param string|int $code Error code. 
* @param string $message Error message. 
* @param mixed $data Optional. Error data. */ 
public function add($code, $message, $data = '') { 
    $this->errors[$code][] = $message; 
    if ( ! empty($data) ) 
        $this->error_data[$code] = $data; 
} 
/** 
* Add data for error code. * 
* The error code can only contain one error data. * 
* @since 2.1.0 * 
* @param mixed $data Error data. 
* @param string|int $code Error code. */ 
public function add_data($data, $code = '') { 
    if ( empty($code) ) $code = $this->get_error_code(); 
    $this->error_data[$code] = $data; 
} 
/** 
* Removes the specified error. * 
* This function removes all error messages associated with the specified 
* error code, along with any error data for that code. * 
* @since 4.1.0 * 
* @param string|int $code Error code. */ 
public function remove( $code ) { 
    unset( $this->errors[ $code ] ); 
    unset( $this->error_data[ $code ] ); 
} 
} 
/** 
* Check whether variable is a WordPress Error. * 
* Returns true if $thing is an object of the WP_Error class. * 
* @since 2.1.0 * 
* @param mixed $thing Check if unknown variable is a WP_Error object. 
* @return bool True, if WP_Error. False, if not WP_Error. */ 
function is_wp_error( $thing ) { 
    return ( $thing instanceof WP_Error ); 
}
```

What could this mean? Outdated PHP code? Outdated Wordpress? Missing modules on the server?

Hopefully someone can help.

Kind regards,
Robin

Answer (score 1):

before a SO moderator removed the link to your site and replaced it with the output (which is very good - it's for your own security) I noticed the link and poked around your site a bit.

It looks like Apache is configured correctly. When I visit /wp-content/index.php for example, I get a nice 200 OK response. That means that index.php is parsed correctly, else you would see in the browser:

```
<?php
// Silence is golden.
```

Which is the content of that file.

Also regular files seem to load normally, like /wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/screenshot.png and /wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css

So "Missing modules on the server" is not the most likely candidate.

Looking at the /readme.html file, it suggests your WP version is 4.2.4 - which is the current latest version, released only two weeks ago. That pretty much rules out "Outdated PHP code and Outdated Wordpress"

I think the problem is a result of "literally copying it to a new host". There are settings in /wp-config.php that may need to change, such as database connection settings, or the path to 'WPCACHEHOME'. There may be entries in the database that contain or are based on URLs with your temporary "localhost" address instead of your new real life website address.

If you look under "Changing Your Domain Name and URLs" on this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
there is a step by step guide how to prepare your site to move it from one server to another when it involves different URLs.

In addition to what's described there - if you had already any caching configured, I suggest to disable caching on your working local version and clear the cache before following those steps and re-enabling them once the site is working on the new location. It looks like the output you see on your screen now, is part of the code of the file /wp-includes/class-wp-error.php which perhaps accidentally got cached as error page.

Answer (score -1):

WordPress is mostly stored in a database. When you say that you copy-pasted the code, did you move the database? Everything in your output you've shown suggests that NULL is the common factor. Something is definitely not connected properly.

If you changed hosts and copied the database, did you make sure to create the exact same username(s) and password(s) used by WordPress in the new hosting?

If not, you're not going to be able to access anything. And WordPress uses the database for almost everything.